Kaggle error Unable to register cuDNN factory, Unable to register cuFFT factory
I tried using GPU support in my kaggle notebook imported the following libraries:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.utils import image_dataset_from_directory

But when tried importing the libraries I got this error and I can't seem to use the gpu support:
2024-04-03 04:22:20.903189: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered

2024-04-03 04:22:20.903245: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered

2024-04-03 04:22:20.904729: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered

What could be the solution to this? I mean cuDNN support may be registered to another notebook I created but then again if that's the case what's the solution to this? I chose "T4 x2" as the accelerator for my notebook.
I tried restarting the kernel but the same problem remains. I tried creating a new notebook, importing all the code, and running it but still, it wasn't of any help.
Update(4/24/2024)

P.S. I chose "T4 x2" as the accelerator And I am facing this error while using tensorflow-keras. If I Use Pytorch there's no issue about it.


he error you're encountering seems to indicate that there's an issue with registering cuDNN, cuFFT, and cuBLAS factories. This could happen if there are conflicting registrations of these plugins or if there's an issue with the GPU environment setup.
Ensure that GPU support is enabled in your Kaggle notebook and that a GPU accelerator is attached to your notebook session. You can verify this by checking the "Accelerator" setting in the "Settings" panel of your Kaggle notebook.Second think Make sure you are using the latest version of TensorFlow available on Kaggle.
